# How to calculate SUM by month by using the max value per day from another query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sum

Actually, what I want to do is to use the output value from my first query :-

```
SELECT pdate, MAX(value_lost) FROM ltime GROUP BY pdate
```

to calculate the SUM of value lost by Month in my second query, but I got no idea on this. Can anyone help me. I get error for my query below:-

```
SELECT MONTH(pdate), SUM(SELECT MAX( value_lost ) 
FROM ltime GROUP BY pdate)) FROM ltime GROUP BY YEAR(pdate),MONTH(pdate);
```

This is what i get if using my first query

[image]

so when I sum, for example the max(value_lost) for March (by month) I will get the value around 36.4757 (for March)

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Add some sample and expected data.

Comment: @cdaiga I edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT MONTH(A.pdate), SUM(A.max_lost_value) 
FROM (SELECT pdate, MAX(value_lost) max_lost_value FROM ltime GROUP BY pdate) A
GROUP BY MONTH(A.pdate);
```

Comment: So so so brilliant!! It works like a charm..tq so much @cdaiga

Answer (score 0):

This query should get you closer to what you need.

```
SELECT MONTH(pdate), SUM(value_lost) as `totalLost`, MAX(value_lost) `highestLost`
   FROM ltime GROUP BY YEAR(pdate), MONTH(pdate)
;
```

Comment: actually this query is little bit different with what I want..anyway, tq so much @Napoli